# Why do Staryu and a few other Pokémon not say their names when all the others do?

Tags: pokemon

All of the Pokémon in the animé say their names when they speak. For instance, Pikachu says "Pikachu" or some variation using those sounds ("Pika", "Chu-Pikachu", "Pi-pi-chu", etc). However, there are a few Pokémon, all from Generation 1 as far as I know, that don't say their names:

- Staryu/Starmie (hiyah!)
- Krabby/Kingler (kookie-kookie!)
- Victreebel (**screaming**)
- Electabuzz (whatever the heck [this is](https://youtu.be/cuOpha_15x4))

Why is it that these Pokémon don't say their names while all the other Pokémon do?

Comment: [Related question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/34095/7579) on Anime and Manga SE.

Comment: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cry

Comment: of note, pokemon *can* learn to say other things. case in point: meowth in the anime.

Comment: @phantom42 Somehow I doubt a Staryu could learn to hold a conversation, what with it lacking a mouth and all.

Comment: Where do you think Staryu's bubbles, water, etc all come out of?

Comment: @phantom but Meowth is a special case, and only the particular Meowth working with Team rocket learned to speak. If I remember correctly he mentioned he gave up all his pokemon power's to learn it. So he talks and behaves like a human but doesn't have any pokabilities that a normal meowth should have

Comment: Yes, but he was a normal Meowth otherwise - not genetically enhanced or with any supernatural abilities. The implication was that any other Meowth (or possibly Pokemon) could do it as well if they trained differently.

Comment: My initial thought is Pokemon don't shout out their names, but a lot of them are named after their most common shout. Like a "Cuckoo" bird, or how a "woodpecker" is named so because it pecks wood.

Comment: @DeeV Unfortunately, that doesn't explain why Kingler is named as such, and not named "Kookie-Kookie".

Comment: @Thunderforge Actually that could be explained by etymology. For example, in the real world a dog's call in the U.S. is "bark bark", but in Japan it is "wan-wan". So depending on where Kingler was discovered may determine the sound that describes his call. (Although admittedly the world of Pokémon doesn't seem to have as diverse dialect as our world.)

Comment: There's also Primeape (and possibly Mankey but I forget) who literally just goes, "bweagh", which sounds a bit like a pig

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- **Electabuzz**

  I can’t find any solid evidence as to why Electabuzz has its bizarre cry. [This](http://pokemonbyreview.blogspot.com/2016/02/239-125-466-elekid-electabuzz-electivire.html) site speculates that Electabuzz was some kind of thunder oni, though [Raijin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raijin) seems a more likely inspiration:

  [image]

  Pictures similar to this famous one, which depicts Raijin with two horn-like protrusions, might have inspired Electabuzz. Its horns also look like Raijin’s drumsticks. If Electabuzz was inspired by Raijin, perhaps its cry is supposed to sound like thunder?

  Maybe.
- **Starmie and Staryu**

  These are easier. As noted [here](http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Staryu):

  > Staryu has a very recognizable personality in the anime to those
  >   familiar with Japanese pop culture. More than any other Pokémon in the
  >   anime, Staryu and Starmie share the mannerisms of their cultural
  >   basis, the 1960s television hero Ultraman (the original Japanese name
  >   Hitodeman is the ultimate clue as hitode is Japanese for starfish).
  >   Staryu’s movement and “kiai” sound mimic Ultraman, but the most
  >   noticeable similarity between them is the jewel on their chests. When
  >   Staryu and Ultraman are low on energy, the jewel begins to blink and
  >   chime a warning alarm.

  Here’s the Staryu sound:

  And here is Ultraman’s sound:
- **Krabby/Kingler**

  These Pokémon make an odd sort of chirping noise:

  Best guess, this is *supposed* to sound like a sound a real crab would make.
- **Victreebel**

  Victreebel basically just screams:

  I cannot even attempt to understand why this is.

Comment: I appreciate this list! If you know any tidbits on other Pokémon with odd cries that I haven't mentioned, feel free to add them!

Comment: Some dead video links here

Answer (score 2):

Electabuzz *is* actually saying its name -- but in *Japanese*, where it's called "Eleboo" (エレブー) instead. Sometimes the localizations leave the original Japanese Pokemon vocalizations intact, which can result in oddities like this when the names have been changed. A similar example is Onix, which is called "Iwark" (イワーク) in Japanese, and can be heard bellowing precisely this.

Comment: Seams reasonable, do you have a source for this?