# According to the anime, which Pokemon don't use their names to communicate?

Tags: anime, languages, pokemon

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/137513/75000) lists a few Pokemon that don't use their names to talk:

- Staryu/Starmie
- Krabby/Kingler
- Victreebel
- Electabuzz

I can think of a couple more:

- Charizard
- Gyarados

Both of these only do a simple roar. There's also [this list](https://nowloading.co/p/all-pokemon-that-talk-like-humans-anime-series-games/4203419) of Pokemon that can speak human languages, but that's not what I'm looking for.

**Specifically, I want to know, according to the anime, which Pokemon do not use their names when they communicate.**

If they do use their names, but have another method of communication (other than telepathy), like sign language, drawing, or something else, that would count as well.

Comment: I understand your intentions with the communications tag, but it's original intent seems to be more along the lines of communication arrays

Comment: @Edlothiad That's weird. Thanks for the *anime* tag though. Forgot about that one. :)

Comment: Well, Meowths who have all their power slots taken up to let them talk like humans. Don't think that's exactly what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

MewTwo *can* speak, but needs a partner in order to. He speaks *telepathically* though. Unlike in  *Pokemon: Detective Pikachu*, where he could speak *physically*.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer any part of the question. I'm looking for non-telepathy, and what do you mean "physically"?